# What is the correct way of getting a membership provider where user id = email?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

I want to implement membership where email is used as the user id. Is there a ready-made provider for this, or do I have to write my own one? Or should I just make do with the 'default' one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the default Sql provider stack without modification.

Simply use an email address as `UserName` (or login id) when creating the user.

Please know that `UserId` is an interal surrogate key.

I think that you are conflating `UserName` (or login id), which is a `string` and can contain an email address, with the `UserId` column in the membership database, which is a `Guid` and should not be changed.